# How to write a method using pointers for Unit Code Testing in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following Unit test code in C. I am trying to write a code that will compile successfully alongside it but no luck at all. It keeps on returning the error `Failed`. At what point could I be going wrong or is there an error with the Unit Test code.
Unit Code is below:

```
#define TEST_LBSG   2494
#define TEST_LBS    5.5 

int testConvertLbsG(void)
{
double lbs = TEST_LBS;
int intA, intB, fail = 0;

printf("---------------------------\n");
printf("Function: convertLbsG\n");
printf("---------------------------\n");

// Test-1: argument and return value
intA = intB = 0;
printf("Test-1: ");
intB = convertLbsG(&lbs, &intA);
if (intA == intB && intA == TEST_LBSG)
{
    printf("<PASSED>\n");
}
else
{
    printf("<!!! FAILED !!!>\n");
    fail++;
}
// Test-2: return value only
intA = intB = 0;
printf("Test-2: ");
intA = convertLbsG(&lbs, NULL);
if (intA == TEST_LBSG)
{
    printf("<PASSED>\n");
}
else
{
    printf("<!!! FAILED !!!>\n");
    fail++;
}

// Test-3: argument only
intA = intB = 0;
printf("Test-3: ");
convertLbsG(&lbs, &intA);
if (intA == TEST_LBSG)
{
    printf("<PASSED>\n");
}
else
{
    printf("<!!! FAILED !!!>\n");
    fail++;
}

return fail;
}
```

The code I am trying to write is as below:

```
int convertLbsG(double* x, int* y) {
if (y == NULL)
{
    return *x;
}
else
{
    return *x = (*y);
}
```

}

Where Am I going wrong

Extra Code:

Assuming this is my unit test code:

```
int testConvertLbs(void)
{
double lbs = TEST_LBS, dblA = 0.0;
int intB = 0, fail = 0;

printf("---------------------------\n");
printf("Function: convertLbs\n");
printf("---------------------------\n");

printf("Test-1: ");
convertLbs(&lbs, &dblA, &intB);
if ((dblA == lbs / TEST_LBSKG) && (intB == TEST_LBSG))
{
    printf("<PASSED>\n\n");
}
else
{
    printf("<!!! FAILED !!!>\n\n");
    fail++;
}

return fail;
}
```

And below is my method:

```
int convertLbs(double* x, double* y, int* z) {
```

}

Comment: "that will compile successfully alongside it" Alongside what? What is the code you are writing a test for? Please at least post the function signature and purpose. And please format the code.

Comment: @Lundin The Unit Test Code. I have described and posted it

Comment: You are trying to write a test that runs alongside your unit test code...? Sorry, but I'm not making any sense of this. What is the test for?

Comment: Very hard to say if it's the test that fails or the code since we have no idea what the code is supposed to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code below:

```
intA = intB = 0;
printf("Test-3: ");
convertLbsG(&lbs, &intA);
if (intA == TEST_LBSG)
```

Only `lhs` is updated, not `intA`. Variable `intA` keeps its old value of `0` and the test fails.

I guess that the intention of `convertLbsG()` was to update the second argument, not the first one .

```
int convertLbsG(double* x, int* y) {
if (y == NULL)
{
    return *x;
}
else
{
    return *y = (*x); // was *x = (*y);
}
```

Moreover, I suggest adding `const` to avoid similar issue in future.

```
int convertLbsG(const double* x, int* y)
```

Comment: The error "Failed" is still being returned

Comment: @Nickson replace `double lbs = TEST_LBS;`  with `double lbs = TEST_LBSG;`

Comment: On a side note, how would one handle one with three parameters instead of two

Comment: @Nickson, please specify the use case

Comment: did you have a look?

Comment: @Nickson, yes. I'm not sure what should be assigned to '*dblA'. Is it 'lbs / TEST_LBSKG'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229855/discussion-between-nickson-and-tstanisl).

Comment: ```#define TEST_LBSKG 2.20462``` That's the value to be assigned.
```dblA``` can take the value from the previous method  ```int convertLbsG(const double* x, int* y)```